# Why doesn't Material Design's layout work with Angular 4?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material

I've installed Material Design as per the Getting Started [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started) but I'm noticing a couple issues when trying replicate the "Responsive Layouts" example at the bottom of the Layout Containers API Reference [page](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/container):

[image]

The layout attribute clearly is not working in my implementation (screen resolution of 1446x150):

[image]

And the Roboto font is clearly not being used when I've specified it in index.html.

I'm hoping that I've missed something blatantly obvious as it would be very disappointing to think that such an easy example is not replicable.

**index.html**

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Personas</title>
    <base href="/">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,400italic">
  </head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  </body>
  </html>
```

**styles.css**

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

**app.component.html**

```
<div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
  <div flex>
    I'm above on mobile, and to the left on larger devices.
  </div>
  <div flex>
    I'm below on mobile, and to the right on larger devices.
  </div>
</div>
```

**Angular**

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 9.2.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 5.1.2
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cdk: 5.0.2
@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular/material: 5.0.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: 3.8.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using angular material 1 syntax on angular (2+), although it's compatible only with angularjs (1). I don't think those are compatible.

Try installing [material 2](https://material.angular.io/)

Flex isn't completely integrated into material 2, it has its [own separate github](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout)

But for now you can achieve what you're showing here either [using grid list](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples)
or by `npm install @angular/flex-layout@latest --save`, however syntax is likely different than angular material 1.

If you prefer the former method, then here's an example taken from angular material 2

in comp.html

```
<mat-grid-list cols="4" rowHeight="100px">
  <mat-grid-tile
    *ngFor="let tile of tiles"
    [colspan]="tile.cols"
    [rowspan]="tile.rows"
    [style.background]="tile.color">
    {{tile.text}}
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

in comp.ts

```
  tiles = [
    {text: 'One', cols: 3, rows: 1, color: 'lightblue'},
    {text: 'Two', cols: 1, rows: 2, color: 'lightgreen'},
    {text: 'Three', cols: 1, rows: 1, color: 'lightpink'},
    {text: 'Four', cols: 2, rows: 1, color: '#DDBDF1'},
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I had originally installed material 2 correctly but did not realize I was looking at v1 documentation.  I ended up installing flex-layout as I'm not sure you to configure the material grid list to switch to a columnar layout as flex layout allows you to do.